# Select MAX and RIGHT OUTER JOIN

Tags: sql, max

I have platform to extract data from sql tables and so far all queries were generated by simple drag and drop tool. Now I am trying to change query manually, but it's not working as expected...

Can you take a look?

Query delivered by generator:

```
SELECT
  repo.MAT.MAT_A_COD,
  inventory.INV.MRP_RQMT_DT,
  SUM(inventory.INV.MRP_AVL_QTY)
  
FROM
  repo.MAT RIGHT OUTER JOIN inventory.INV ON (inventory.INV.MRP_MAT_A_FK=repo.MAT.MAT_A_PK)
  
WHERE
  ( inventory.INV.MRP_COMPANY_COD IN ('01','02')  )
  
GROUP BY
  1, 
  2
```

Results:

```
Material A | 2020.01.01 | 100
Material A | 2020.01.02 | 200
Material A | 2020.01.03 | 300
Material B | 2020.01.01 | 10
Material B | 2020.01.02 | 0
```

What I am looking for: only values for the latest date for each material.

```
Material A | 2020.01.03 | 300
Material B | 2020.01.02 | 0
```

I tried with MAX(inventory.INV.MRP_RQMT_DT), but no success. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below -

```
SELECT
  repo.MAT.MAT_A_COD,
  inventory.INV.MRP_RQMT_DT,
  SUM(inventory.INV.MRP_AVL_QTY)
FROM
  repo.MAT RIGHT OUTER JOIN inventory.INV ON inventory.INV.MRP_MAT_A_FK=repo.MAT.MAT_A_PK
WHERE
  inventory.INV.MRP_COMPANY_COD IN ('01','02') and inventory.INV.MRP_RQMT_DT=(select max(inventory.INV.MRP_RQMT_DT) from inventory.INV inv1 where inventory.INV.MRP_MAT_A_FK=inv1.MRP_MAT_A_FK)
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify the database engine, but the RANK windows function works in many major ones (I will use T-SQL syntax).

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
       repo.MAT.MAT_A_COD,
       inventory.INV.MRP_RQMT_DT,
       SUM(inventory.INV.MRP_AVL_QTY),
       RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY repo.MAT.MAT_A_COD ORDER BY inventory.INV.MRP_RQMT_DT) rn
  
    FROM repo.MAT RIGHT OUTER JOIN inventory.INV ON (inventory.INV.MRP_MAT_A_FK=repo.MAT.MAT_A_PK)
  
    WHERE inventory.INV.MRP_COMPANY_COD IN ('01','02')
  
    GROUP BY 1, 2
)
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
SELECT m.MAT_A_COD,  i.MRP_RQMT_DT,
       SUM(i.MRP_AVL_QTY) 
FROM repo.MAT LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT i.*, 
             MAX(MRP_RQMT_DT) OVER (PARTITION BY MRP_MAT_A_FK ORDER BY DESC) as max_MRP_RQMT_DT
      FROM inventory.INV i
     ) i
     ON i.MRP_MAT_A_FK = r.MAT_A_PK AND
        i.MRP_RQMT_DT = i.max_MRP_RQMT_DT  
WHERE i.MRP_COMPANY_COD IN ('01', '02')  
GROUP BY 1, 2;
```

Note other changes to the query:

- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- An outer join does not seem necessary at all.  But if you do use one, it is probably on the `MAT` table, not the `inventory` table.
- If you use an outer join, you should try to take the columns from the table where you are keeping all the rows -- the first table in a `LEFT JOIN`.  I don't recommend `RIGHT JOIN`s in general.